# Prevent form subscription in ReactJS input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an HTML form in my project, which is partially written with React (Don't ask me why. Historical issues.) Consider it to look like this:

```html
<html>
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<div id="app"><!-- React component here --></div>
</form>
</html>
```

Then the react code, effectively like this:

```javascript
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>,
  app // consider this is the #app element
);
```

How can I stop the form from submitting with "enter" key by just changing the `input` element in my React component? Or is it possible?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to submit on Enter anyway, there's more than one input field in the form. Normally, browsers only submit-on-enter in a text field if the text field is the only field in the form.

Comment: Working on a component that will dynamically generate text field (behave like textarea). Just want to prevent users from submitting the form by pressing "Enter" in my component.

Comment: From my experience, "Submit on Enter" works on any text field in the form (even if there are multiple text field).

Comment: Certainly not mine. For instance, [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr7xbrhe/) with just one input submits if you put your cursor in the field and press Enter, but [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/hr7xbrhe/1/) with a secod input does not -- I just tested Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 (the browsers I have handy).

Comment: You're right. If your form do not have a submit button, the "Submit on Enter" will be de-activated for multi-field form. But my form do have a submit button. So it is practically [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/hr7xbrhe/2/). :-(

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `onKeydown` handler on the `input` accepting the event parameter as `e` and, in the handler, if `e.which` is 13, call `e.preventDefault` to prevent the default action.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Tried `onKeyUp`, `onKeyPress` and it didn't work. `onKeyDown` do the trick.